# How to have apply Worksheet_Change to more than one cell?

Tags: excel, vba, timestamp

I implemented code to timestamp a cell whenever a condition in another cell in the same row is manually met:

```vb
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal target As Range)

    Dim A As Range: Set A = Range("A2:A2800")
    Dim v As String
    If Intersect(target, A) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    v = target.Value
    If v = "" Then target.Offset(0, 6) = ""
    If v = "Solicitud enviada" Then target.Offset(0, 6) = Date
      
    Application.EnableEvents = True

End Sub
```

I need to timestamp another cell by a different criteria. I know I can't have two `Worksheet_Change` subs at the same time, but from what I've investigated trying to have two events at the same time goes beyond me.

```vb
Private Sub LeadTimeStamp(ByVal target As Range)

    Dim D As Range: Set D = Range("D2:D2800")
    Dim b As String
    If Intersect(target, D) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub

    Application.EnableEvents = False
    b = target.Value
    If b = "" Then target.Offset(0, 8) = ""
    If b = "lead" Then target.Offset(0, 8) = Date

    Application.EnableEvents = True

End Sub
```

`b` needs to be compared as a string array with the cell, something like `b.length <= 10` if this was JavaScript.
I know that VBA uses `LEN()`, but I do not know how to use it here. For now I have a placeholder condition similar to the one on the original code, to make sure that the code works before I tackle the array condition part.

Answer (score 1):

Your situation is that you need to check for one of several possible changes, so that means an `If` statement at the `Target` level. So in outline form it would look like this:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    '--- only deal with single-cell changes. multi-cell
    '    edits are skipped
    If Target.CountLarge > 1 Then Exit Sub

    Dim solicitudArea As Range
    Dim leadArea As Range
    Set solicitudArea = Range("A2:A2800")
    Set leadArea = Range("D2:D2800")

    Application.EnableEvents = False
    If Not Intersect(target, solicitudArea) Is Nothing Then
        '--- a request has changed
        If Target.Value = vbNullString Then 
            Target.Offset(0, 6).Value = vbNullString
        ElseIf Target.Value = "Solicitud enviada" Then 
            Target.Offset(0, 6).Value = Date()
        End If
    ElseIf Not Intersect(target, leadArea) Is Nothing Then
        '--- a request has changed
        If Target.Value = vbNullString Then 
            Target.Offset(0, 8).Value = vbNullString
        ElseIf Target.Value = "lead" Then 
            Target.Offset(0, 8).Value = Date()
        End If
    End If
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

A good practice is to use variable names that match up with what those values represent. It makes the code easier to read and maintain later on.